# Ajax can not connect to C# method in asp.net core razore page in this Ajax is not Working

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to Serialized my model object value and pass it into C# Method .Here is my Ajax Code

```
$("#btnSave").click(() => {
var options = {};
options.type = "Post";
options.url = "/Order/Create?handler=Create";

var obj = {};
obj.OrderNo = parseInt( $("#OrderNo").val());

let OrderDate = new Date($("#OrderDate").val())
obj.OrderDate = OrderDate;
obj.CustomerId = parseInt($("#CustomerId").val());

var orderDetails = new Array();
$("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var orderDetail = {};
    orderDetail.Qty = parseFloat(row.find("TD").eq(0).html());
    orderDetail.UnitPrice = parseFloat(row.find("TD").eq(1).html());
    orderDetail.DiscountPercentage = parseInt(row.find("TD").eq(2).html());
    orderDetail.OrderNo = parseInt($("#OrderNo").val());
    orderDetails.push(orderDetail);
});
obj.OrderDetail = orderDetails;
options.data = JSON.stringify(obj);
options.contentType = "application/json";
options.dataType = "json";

options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("MY-XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
};
options.success = function (msg) {
    $("#msg").html(msg);
};
options.error = function () {
    $("#msg").html("Error while making Ajax call!");
};
$.ajax(options);});
```

Here is my C# Method

```
 public JsonResult OnPostCreate([FromBody]Order obj)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [Order]( OrderNo, OrderDate, CustomerId) VALUES('" + obj.OrderNo + "','" + obj.OrderDate + "','" + obj.CustomerId + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        foreach (OrderDetail orderDetail in obj.OrderDetail)
        {
            string query2 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetail (Qty, UnitPrice, DiscountPercentage, OrderNo) VALUES('" + orderDetail.Qty + "','" + orderDetail.UnitPrice + "','" + orderDetail.DiscountPercentage + "','" + obj.OrderNo + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

            con.Open();
            int Result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        return Json();
    }
```

Here is My Class

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=PPL;User ID=sa;Password=alituhin1");

    private readonly PPL.Data.PPLContext _context;

    public CreateModel(PPL.Data.PPLContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Order.Add(Order);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    //.......Own..
    //[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult OnPostCreate([FromBody]Order obj)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [Order]( OrderNo, OrderDate, CustomerId) VALUES('" + obj.OrderNo + "','" + obj.OrderDate + "','" + obj.CustomerId + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        foreach (OrderDetail orderDetail in obj.OrderDetail)
        {
            string query2 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetail (Qty, UnitPrice, DiscountPercentage, OrderNo) VALUES('" + orderDetail.Qty + "','" + orderDetail.UnitPrice + "','" + orderDetail.DiscountPercentage + "','" + obj.OrderNo + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

            con.Open();
            int Result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        return Json();
    }

    private JsonResult Json()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    //...........end

}
```

1. I am facing a problem to call the method.
   2.I can not find the problem where is wrong

[image: Here is folder Image]

Comment: Is the calling ajax url correct - "/Order/Create?handler=Create"? Because your class doesn't have this  route.

Comment: Be careful with those perfect victims for SQLi. Use SqlCommand parameters instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: You can first use f12 to check if there is a error when you click the button. Have you add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your razor page and configure it in your startup.cs like this:`services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "MY-XSRF-TOKEN");`? For Handling Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, you can refer to [this atricle](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

Comment: mj1313 I have given but I can not find the problem where is wrong. I think here exist routing problem

Comment: @Md.AliHaider So, is there any error message?

Comment: Thanks Everyone ,I have solved my problem